# How to display small size image as large size image without losing the clarity of image in android?

Tags: java, android

I want to display the background image for one image view and text view.My problem is my background image should grow and shrink depending on it's child views without losing the image quality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can define specific regions within your background that should stretch versus areas that should stay anchored in the same position regardless of size, [9-patches](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch) may be what you are looking for. These are perfect for creating resizable frames for content.

Comment: Thank you . I achieved this by 9-patches

Answer (score 0):

You can use setDensity(int density) method on Bitmap. You can change the density every time you want to change the size of the image.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#setDensity(int)